# jquery paging - elements nested in href don't link to correct pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, paging

So I'm using jquery to access different pages within the same body. Clicking the li space links to the correct page, however clicking anywhere near the img/icon (contained in a div) or the text (contained in a span) switches to a completely blank page. Suggestions?

For the ease of demo, I've switched the img div to a bordered box for placement. The extra js is for animation I also removed for the sake of keeping this a bit smaller.

fiddle link:  http://jsfiddle.net/nL4D6/

thanks in advance!

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="pages">
            <div id="page1" class="current">
            <p>page 1</p>
            </div>
            <div id="page2">
            <p>page 2</p>
            </div>
            <div id="page3">
            <p>page 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
<footer>
    <ul id="tab-bar">
        <li>
            <a href="#page1"><div id="img1"></div><span>Page1</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#page2"><div id="img2"></div><span>Page2</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#page3"><div id="img3"></div><span>Page3</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper
{
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
top:45px;
bottom:48px;
width:100%;
overflow:auto;
}

#content {
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
width:100%;
padding:0;
}

#pages
{
position: relative;
}

#pages > div
{
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
}

#pages > div.current
{
display: block;
}

#tab-bar
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 900;
}

#tab-bar li
{
display: inline;
float: left;
border-left: 1px solid #000000;
width: 33.333%
}

#img1
{
display: block;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto 2px auto;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid blue;
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
opacity: 0.5;
}

#img2
{
display: block;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto 2px auto;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid blue;
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
opacity: 0.5;
}

#img3
{
display: block;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto 2px auto;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid blue;
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
opacity: 0.5;
}

#tab-bar a
{
color: #ffffff;
background: #ab1b1b;
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
font-size: 0.9em;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 6px 0 2px 0;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

#tab-bar a:hover
{
background: #d43333;
}

#tab-bar a:hover > #img1,
#tab-bar a:hover > #img2,
#tab-bar a:hover > #img3
{
opacity: 1;
}
```

JS

```
$('#tab-bar a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var nextPage = $(e.target.hash);
    page(nextPage); //You need to add this for it to work
    $("#pages .current").removeClass("current");
    nextPage.addClass("current");
})

function page(toPage) {
    var toPage = $(toPage),
            fromPage = $("#pages .current");
    if(toPage.hasClass("current") || toPage === fromPage) {
        return;
    };
    toPage.addClass("current fade in").one("webkitAnimationEnd", function(){
        fromPage.removeClass("current fade out");
        toPage.removeClass("fade in")
    });
    fromPage.addClass("fade out");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach was using the `$(e.target.hash)`

`target` always corresponds to the **element that was clicked.** 
`currentTarget` corresponds to **element to which the event was bound** to.

So when you click on the image element your `target` points to image **and not anchor**.

Instead of

```
var nextPage = $(e.target.hash);
```

Try this instead

`var nextPage = $(e.currentTarget.hash);`

**Or Better**

```
var nextPage = this.hash;
```

Comment: My lack of js knowledge is starting to show strongly the more I try to work it in. Thank you for the detailed explanation, works perfectly now. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't put `<div>` inside `<a>`.

There are roughly 2 types of HTML elements: block-level elements and inline elements. Block level elements are for instance `<div>`. Inline elements are `<span> <strong> <a> <p>` and so on.

Now logically you can nest block level elements in block level elements, and inline elements in inline elements, and you can nest level inline elements in block level elements. But you *can't* nest block level elements in inline elements.

Your browser is likely splitting your HTML. So:

```
<a href="link">text1<div>text2</div>text3</a>
```

Becomes:

```
<a href="link">text1</a><div>text2</div><a ??>text3</a>
```

Comment: HTML 5 allows block elements inside of `</a>` elements.

Comment: Hadn't thought of this when constructing it... However js does allow me to cheat some rules here and there :) Upvote for detailed explanation though! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using jQuery you can simply use `var nextPage = $( this.hash );` instead of `e.target.hash`.

Comment: Your answer is right as well, just a bit after sushanth! Thanks for the input and thoughts. Upvoted.